# How to call a method with spaces in the name?

Tags: python, syntax, identifier

I have the following class:

```
Help on class A in module a:

class A(__builtin__.object)
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  any vegetable(self)
 |      TODO document this
 |  
 |  getHeight(self)
 |      uses the chicken to measure it
```

Calling `any vegetable` doesn't work:

```
>>> a.A().any vegetable()
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    a.A().any vegetable()
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I call `any vegetable`?

---

Okay, I can't believe I have to provide more proof but here goes.

```
>>> dir(a.A)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'any vegetable', 'getHeight']
```

This isn't my class, so please don't tell me to rewrite it. I just need to call the method.

Comment: Python takes its whitespace very seriously, you can't have a space in a method name. Replace it with an underscore

Comment: that isnt valid python ....

Comment: For a moment there I thought "any vegetable" was a Python library of some sort.

Comment: Invalid python? I think not! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651733/python-use-spaces-in-a-function-name

Comment: @RobertHarvey: You are slightly motivating me to write a library called `vegetable`. Not quite sure what it should do just yet. Perhaps it can provide stubbing functionalities for functions while testing

Comment: @Snoozer: It *does* have a space in it. See the doc I pasted above.

Comment: The answer is getattr(a.A(), "any vegetable")() well you will need to pass an instance I guess

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `getattr`:

```
>>> a = A()
>>> getattr(a, 'any vegetable')()
```

Note that having names with weird characters such as spaces in them is a ***very, very bad idea***. No sane person would ever do this.

Comment: It has a method called `any vegetable`. See the doc I pasted.

Comment: That's impossible unless `setattr` or similar functions are used.

Comment: well then perhaps "setattr or similar functions were used"

Comment: @Dog: is this some sort of puzzle?  No one would ever do this in real code.

Comment: @DSM, no it is not. I renamed everything before pasting here though so they aren't realistic names, except for the fact that there is a space in the method name.

Comment: @Dog: find the authors of this code.  Hit them repeatedly with a foam-based cluebat.  Repeat as necessary.

Comment: @DSM Must be some sort of obfuscation by obscurity.

Comment: The author was really protective of their vegetables